# Kubuntu not starting up after cloning HDD to SSD (dual-boot)

Tags: dual-boot, startup

My Acer Aspire 3 was really slow recently, so I decided to upgrade to an SSD (Samsung 860 QVO). To clone the HDD to the SSD, I used 'MiniTool Partition Wizard' on my Desktop PC with both drives connected as additional drives. After that was complete, I put the SSD into my Laptop and reorganized the boot order so it doesn't boot windows first.

When I select Kubuntu to boot up in the menu, it sets me into 'emergency mode'. I checked the system logs, and the errors (while booting in recovery mode) are:

```
Couldn't get size:  0x800000000000000e
```

```
dell_smbios: unable to run on non-Dell system
```

```
Timed out while waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2255\x2dF32A.device
```

The second one seems to be just a warning, nothing critical as far as my current research lead me, and the third one occurs three times.

Windows boots up completely fine.
If I don't boot in recovery mode, the mount of my data partition fails sometimes too.

What do I need to do? I have no clue...

/etc/fstab content:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>      <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=99003951-3d2a-4d2a-9f8c-819ebce625f5     /     ext4    errors=remount-ro    0    1
# /boot/efi was on /def/sda1 during installation
UUID=2255-F32A  /boot/efi        vfat    umask=0077    0    1
/swapfile    none   swap   sw    0    0
/dev/sda4    /media/name/DATA      ext4   defaults     0    0
```

Left the potentially relevant comments in. Maybe got some space counting wrong

lsblk returns:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN  RM    SIZE  RO  TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0     0     89M   1  loop  /snap/core/7713
loop1     7:1     0  181,9M   1  loop  /snap/spotify/36
loop2     7:2     0  180,2M   1  loop  /snap/spotify/35
loop3     7:3     0   88,7M   1  loop  /snap/core/7396
sda       8:0     0  931,5G   0  disk
 sda1     8:1     0    100M   0  part
 sda2     8:2     0     16M   0  part
 sda3     8:3     0    250G   0  part
 sda4     8:4     0  616,4G   0  part /media/name/DATA
 sda5     8:5     0     64G   0  part /
 sda6     8:6     0      1G   0  part
```

sda3 has windows on it
sda4 is my storage partition
sda5 has Kubuntu on it

blkid

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="ESP" UUID="BE40-0410" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="be400c10-745b-01d5-0802-20df2dbaea00"
/dev/sda2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="becf2cb0-745b-01d5-5892-67df2dbaea00"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Acer" UUID="01D5745E44AB9120" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="00109877-9120-44ab-5efc-d701ee302100"
/dev/sda4: UUID="df63cc42-06a5-41f0-b43c-775ba196f4bb" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="9f73fbf0-745f-01d5-f86d-b8c02fbaea00"
/dev/sda5: UUID="99003951-3d9a-4d2a-9f8c-819ebce625f5" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="002e5b03-0de0-cf2b-627c-d56d06b65c00"
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="01D57462D38BA8E0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="f7d06bd0-7462-01d5-e831-c86931baea00"
```

Comment: Not sure about the first error, the second one should be negligable, the third one should be your problem. It is trying to mount a partition it can't find. Either your clone tool changed the `UUID` or it is somehow missing. To fix/check that, you can boot a live os and check `/etc/fstab` and run `blkid` and post the output.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I need `blkid` in addition to that. It will tell us the current assigned `UUID`s.

Comment: Looks like the EFI partition fails to be mounted though. You can comment the line out like that: `#UUID=2255-F32A  /boot/efi        vfat    umask=0077    0    1`. If that was the problem, it should boot up fine and you can fix that later.

Comment: It actually did boot up after commenting that out

Comment: Is it just fixed now or is there still something left to do?

Comment: Yes, you should fix that because when the bootloader is updated, it needs that partition mounted. You need to find the `UUID` of the EFI Partition (It's not sda4...). It will have `vfat` as a filesystem. Mount it first and check the content.

Comment: I think I see. I need to change the UUID in fstab to be40-0410, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly! After that and a reboot or running `mount -a`, you should see the contents under `/boot/efi` again and updates shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: everything is working as intended now :)

Comment: glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the `UUID` of the EFI Partition has been changed (maybe by the clone tool). During startup, Kubuntu is trying to mount it and fails as it can't find it under that identifier.

To fix that, edit the entry in `/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>      <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=99003951-3d2a-4d2a-9f8c-819ebce625f5     /     ext4    errors=remount-ro    0    1
# /boot/efi was on /def/sda1 during installation
UUID=BE40-0410  /boot/efi        vfat    umask=0077    0    1
/swapfile    none   swap   sw    0    0
/dev/sda4    /media/name/DATA      ext4   defaults     0    0
```